# Implementing FusionChart.js in Lightning Component(Locker Service)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, locker-service

I want to implement fusionchart.js in lightning component. I have implemented it in visualforce page using fusionchart CDN. As we cannot use CDN in lightning component due to locker service, I implement this by uploading same file as static resource. But I am getting JavaScript error in fusionchart.js

1. Can anyone please guide me how to implement fusionchart in lightning component?
2. Below link has list of non- exhaustive libraries that are known to work with LockerService. Can we use libraries other than mentioned in below link(example fusionchart.js, blockUI.js etc. )?

   https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html
3. If yes, How to check if a particular third party application is compatible with lightning or not ?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: I dont think with lightning components you can use CDN links. we had a similar requirement for bing maps and we used a iframe inside a lightning component and used VF to implement the same.

Comment: Yes. I am not using CDN. I am using static resource. I am getting javascript error in js file while loading of file

Comment: Can you provide more details about the JavaScript error?